# hibernate-memcached statistics

Tags: java, hibernate, memcached

I recently switched over my hibernate second level cache from EHcache to memcached using the hibernate-memcached implementation. This is working out really good for me. 
The problem I am currently having with this is that I had created a page that I used to monitor the lvl2 cache statistics. This was implemented using the HibernateStats class. However now that I switched to memcached this page displays -1 as the count for every cache region.

I have gone through the memcached-hibernate code and indeed these methods have been implemented to always return -1. I was wondering if anybody has a solution for this, or any general idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all stats using stats method.

```
Map<String, String> stats = client.getStats().get(client.getStats().keySet().toArray()[0]);
```

You can get whole data or data regarding to specific keys.

Comment: Agreed this gives you access to the memcached server statistics. But those aren't really helpfull to get an overview of what kind of entities and how much are currently in the cache?